# How to deploy Sonar + Jenkins on a server

Tags: linux, apache, jenkins, server, sonarqube

I managed to deploy Jenkins and Sonar on my local machine. So I have a Jenkins job that will run a SonarQube analysis on a remote Git repository. However, I have to do this again from a server but I really do not know how to do it ..

Answer (score 0):

The process should be similar to your local setup though you should consider using the hosted services for simplicity and scalability.

1. Install Jenkins on your favorite platform, AWS/Azure/etc. You'll likely want to:

   - Set up a DNS entry for the Jenkins server
   - Configure an SSL certificate to encrypt traffic between your servers
   - Provision at least one build agent
2. Install SonarQube on a separate server on your favorite cloud platform.

   - Set up a DNS entry for the server
   - Generate an SSL certificate
3. Configure SonarQube making sure to disable anonymous users
4. Configure Jenkins by

   - installing SonarScanner Plugin and its prerequisites
   - Configure a job to, hopefully, set up a webhook to trigger builds from your Git provider.